# Update PHP statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xcode, sql-update

Need help with this php statement, SQL and SQLTWO is not working. I believe it has to do with the MATH part.

i have done one similar to this
 and it worked. I'm trying to do a little math with in the php file be for it in puts into the database. I know it would be easier to do the formula in Xcode before i send it but the values may change before my data is received in the phone and i want the most current data. If you have any question or suggestions please let me know... Thank you if you made it this far lol.

```
    <?php
    $DB_HostName = "HostName";
    $DB_User = "UserName";
    $DB_Pass = "Password";
// Connect to server and select databse.
$conn = mysql_connect("$DB_HostName", "$DB_User", "$DB_Pass")or die("cannot connect");
if(! $conn )
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'MySQL Connected successfully'."<BR>";
mysql_select_db("Database") or die(mysql_error());
echo "Connected to Database"."<BR>";
$userID= 8 ;
$Health= 100 ;
$Hits= 120 ;
$Rank= 5 ;
$Power= 25 ;
$Skills= 150 ;
$userSPRH=  5235 ;

$USERID= 5 ;
$userWORTH= 22653 ;

$sql = "UPDATE UserProfile ".
       "SET 
//MATH ....
$RH = $RANK * $HEALTH ,
$SP = $Skills + $POWER ,
$SPRH = $RH + $SP ,
$Power = $SPRH - $userSPRH ,
$HitCash = $POWER - $userWORTH ,
$PR = $POWER * $RANK ,
$SR = $Skills * $RANK ,
$SPRR = $SR + $PR ,
// MATH END
//DATE TO UPDATE
Health = Health - $POWER ,
Worth = $SPRR * $HEALTH ,
Cash = Cash - $HitCash
".
 "WHERE userID = $userID " ;
$sqlTWO = "UPDATE UserProfile ".
       "SET 
Worth = Worth + $userWORTH ,
Cash = Cash + $HitCash 
".
  "WHERE userID = $USERID " ;
$result=mysql_query($sql);
if ($result)
{
    echo "Update 1 Successfully";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Thank God</a>";
}
$result=mysql_query($sqlTWO);
if ($result)
{
    echo "Update 2 Successfully";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "YESSSSSS</a>";
}    else {
    echo "ERROR";
    // close connection 
    mysql_close();
}
?>
```

Comment: You want _me_ to come up with the question?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: no, I'm trying to get this to work, whats wrong with it?

Comment: Just get the math part out of the string part.

Comment: If i place it on top of the SQL part is will error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are not connecting to database. you variables are strings.

change this

```
   $conn = mysql_connect("$DB_HostName", "$DB_User", "$DB_Pass")
```

to

```
  $conn = mysql_connect($DB_HostName, $DB_User, $DB_Pass)
```

and your update is wrong . you have to use math part outside the query, try use  this

```
         $RH = $RANK * $HEALTH ;
         $SP = $Skills + $POWER ;
        $SPRH = $RH + $SP ;
       $Power = $SPRH - $userSPRH ;
       $HitCash = $POWER - $userWORTH ;
        $PR = $POWER * $RANK ;
        $SR = $Skills * $RANK ;
       $SPRR = $SR + $PR ;


 $sql = " UPDATE UserProfile SET 

       Health = Health - $POWER ,
       Worth = $SPRR * $HEALTH ,
       Cash = Cash - $HitCash
       WHERE userID = $userID  ";
```

Comment: This makes no difference, but you're right.

Comment: The Connection works... Its the MATH part i just made a edit. Thanks

Comment: i have commented , to use column names instead of the variables.

Comment: @user3777110 look edited answer in the query

Comment: Thank you you all, and to the edits it really wasn't a dumb question. cause its a wonderful scrip i just did cap a coupe of the works. Thank again